# Unable to pass apt-get -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success or similar option to apt

Tags: command-line, apt

I need to pass a command line option to apt in order to hook the execution of  of apt-get install/update.

I know this can be done changing the configuration files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, but I want to be able to do it from command line, because i need it only a few times.

Specifically, I want to be able to execute a script, which for testing purposes I locaed in `/home/jake/agio`.

Unfortunately, apt-get does not seems to be very prone to printing the errors or the reason why this is not working. And obviously I have tested the script and is working.

I think I have tried all the possible combinations of options for apt-get:

```
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success="/home/jake/agio" update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success={"/home/jake/agio"} update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success={"/home/jake/agio"\;} update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success={"/home/jake/agio "} update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success=/home/jake/agio update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success=/home/jake/agio update


apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke="/home/jake/agio" install youtube-dl
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio"} install youtube-dl
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio"\;} install youtube-dl
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio "} install youtube-dl
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke=/home/jake/agio install youtube-dl
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke=/home/jake/agio install youtube-dl


apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke="/home/jake/agio" update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio"} update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio"\;} update
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke={"/home/jake/agio "} update 
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke=/home/jake/agio update  
apt-get -y remove youtube-dl &&  apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes -o DPkg::Post-Invoke=/home/jake/agio update
```

Can you help me?!

`-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes` is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I inspect existing `apt` configuration, I see:

```
~ apt-config dump | grep -i dpkg::post
DPkg::Post-Invoke "";
DPkg::Post-Invoke:: "if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";
```

And so trying out variations, it looks like the correct form would be `-o DPkg::Post-Invoke::=/home/jake/agio`:

```
$ apt-config -o DPKG::Post-invoke::='foo bar' dump | grep -i DPkg::Post
DPkg::Post-Invoke "";
DPkg::Post-Invoke:: "if [ -d /var/lib/update-notifier ]; then touch /var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp; fi; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available 2>/dev/null || true";
DPkg::Post-Invoke:: "foo bar";
```

And indeed:

```
~ sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Post-Invoke::='foo bar' install snapd-          
Reading package lists... Done
[...]
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
sh: 1: foo: not found
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'foo bar'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion - however I'm still confused why `DPKG::Post-invoke='foo bar'` doesn't work, since it appears to insert `foo bar` as the *first* item in the list (replacing the empty string).

Comment: @steeldriver the way the output looks, I think the list members all come in the `::` subsection, so maybe the empty string is not the first item in the list or part of the list at all, but some other attribute of `Post-Invoke` that doesn't have any meaning.